# Tokenize a string in KornShell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh, tokenize

I need to tokenize in string in KornShell (ksh). I have got the following script for bash; but it does not seem to work in ksh.

The script is below. Please help in making work for ksh.

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
read -a array <<< "$(printf "%s" "$APPLICATION_NAMES")"
IFS=$OLDIFS
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   :
   # do whatever on $i
   echo "Checking status of $i"
done
```

Comment: `read -a` and `<<<` are bash features, not ksh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# s=a,b,c
# IFS=,
# set -A arr $s
# for e in "${arr[@]}"; do print -- "$e"; done
a
b
c
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks a lot, am able to tokenize the string with the provided scritp, Thanks once again